# Radius of convergence of complex power series using Cauchy's integral formula

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, cauchy-integral-formula

I have a question as follows. Let

$$f(z)=\frac{\sin z}{(z-1-i)^2}$$

and

$$a_n=\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$$

Determine the radius of convergence of

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$$

In my class we have talked extensively about Cauchy's Integral Formula as well as power series, and we've often used

$$\frac{1}{R}=\limsup_{n \to 0}\left\lvert \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right\rvert$$

to determine radius of convergence. The main issue I'm having is determining a closed form for $f^{(n)}(0)$. I have taken multiple derivatives of $f(z)$ and have not noticed any sort of pattern. I suspect I'm supposed to utilize Cauchy's Integral Formula in some way in order to do this (I could be wrong); however, I'm unsure on how to do so. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know the fact that if f is analytic in D(0,r), then its Taylor series converges in D(0,r)?

Comment: By D(0, r) do you mean a disc of radius r?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ has a singularity at $z=1+i$.

The radius of convergence of the Taylor series of $f$ around the origin is the distance from the origin to the singularity, $\sqrt 2$ in this case.

The reason is simple:

- If $R < \sqrt2$, then $f$ is holomorphic in the disk of radius $R$ centered at the origin.
- If $R \ge \sqrt2$, then $f$ is not holomorphic in the disk of radius $R$ centered at the origin because it is not even defined at the singularity.

Comment: Thanks! I was unaware of this fact but it makes sense intuitively.